# Lazy evaluation and/or flexible macro names

Tags: c++, logging, macros, lazy-evaluation, c++03

I have a simple single-header logging library. I'd like to "embed" it into other libraries I write, so that a user could selectively turn on logging for different parts of the application. I don't want to add any dependencies, which is why the single-header nature is so appealing. In order for the different copies of the same logging library to not conflict with each other, I can stick individual copies inside the target library's namespace, isolating everything that needs to be isolated. That part is simple enough.

There is one problem, however. The logging library has a macro, `LOG_SEV(severity)` that one actually uses to stick a message into a particular stream. The reason for the macro is that I need to prepend some kind of `if (logging conditions hold) ...` to ensure lazy evaluation of the messages.

Being a macro, it pollutes the global namespace and I get at the very least warning messages (and possibly conflicts). I wonder if there is a way around this problem. Either some other way of doing lazy evaluation (in C++03, not C++11), or some way to augment the macro name with the target library name, turning `LOG_SEV(severity)` into `LOG_SEV_mylib(severity)`. Or is this hopeless?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example?

Answer (score 1):

C++03 (or later) can use **[boost::proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/proto.html#boost_proto.preface)** to generate an expression object that hasn't yet been evaluated.

Their ["hello world" example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/proto/users_guide.html#boost_proto.users_guide.getting_started.hello_world) (verbatim, below) comes close to what you describe.

Imagine your *logging conditions* in the `evaluate` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>
#include <boost/typeof/std/ostream.hpp>
using namespace boost;

proto::terminal< std::ostream & >::type cout_ = { std::cout };

template< typename Expr >
void evaluate( Expr const & expr )
{
    proto::default_context ctx;
    proto::eval(expr, ctx);
}

int main()
{
    evaluate( cout_ << "hello" << ',' << " world" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. I guess the crux of the idea (if I wanted to avoid having `boost::proto` as a dependency) is to overload operators for the `terminal`, build up an expression, and evaluate it only if the conditions hold. I think I could make it look even cleaner than passing to `evaluate()`; something like build a temporary and evaluate-on-destruction. Thank you very much for this; it's a great solution.

Comment: Actually, wait a second. This seems to have a problem. If there is an (expensive) function call inside the expression, something like `cout_ << expensive()`, it will get evaluated no matter what. I'd like to avoid that possibility.